# asp.net - How to find outlook mail attachment by ContentId Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I can find email attachment from a **MailMessage** by ContenId like the following code :

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage objNewMail = null;
System.Net.Mail.Attachment FindAttachment = objNewMail.Attachments.First(x => x.ContentId == "ii_157d139a0005732b");
```

But, I want to find out the attachment from **Outlook.MailItem** by ContenId.
I tried many times, but **Outlook.MailItem** do not have a property like **ContentId**.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` in the Outlook Object Model. `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property can be accessed by its DASL property name (`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`).

Take a look at the message and its attachments with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

Comment: Can you please explain this, because I tried many times with Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. but I am getting the following message : "cannot be parsed or has an invalid format."

Comment: Yes, It worked for me.  I got a complete explanation from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4693174/2862736